# Dependency in IRT with pseudoitems as a testlet

Tags: independence, item-response-theory

I'm curious whether a testlet IRT model would be appropriate for a situation where polytomous responses on a 1-5 scale are decomposed into pseudoitems indicating whether the response is $\ge X$

response 1 = 0,0,0,0
response 2 = 1,0,0,0
response 3 = 1,1,0,0
response 4 = 1,1,1,0
response 5 = 1,1,1,1

So instead of 1 item on a 1-5 scale, there would be 4 binary items treated as a testlet.  I know this violates independence, but don't know if the violation is "too strong" for a testlet model to correct.

Help appreciated.

**Edit to clarify:**

I'm thinking of a response on a 1-5 scale.  Say 4.  I want to decompose this polytomous response into a series of pseudoitems, similar to the multiprocess model or DeBoeck's IRTree.  There are 4 pseudoitems:

1. is the response $\ge2$ (1 yes 0 no)
2. is the response $\ge3$ (1 yes 0 no)
3. is the response $\ge 4$ (1 yes 0 no)
4. is the response $\ge 5$ (1 yes 0 no)

(there is no pseudoitem for $\ge 1$ because that would always be true for any non-missing response)

If the response was 4, then the pseudoitem response pattern would be 1,1,1,0  ($\ge 2$ "yes", $\ge 3$ "yes", $\ge 4$ "yes", $\ge5$ "no").  So from 1 item, there are now 4.

But, this creates dependency.  I want to know if the testlet model (something based on Wainer, Bradlow, & Wang) can accommodate this by modeling the 4 pseudoitems as a testlet, which is necessarily dependent.

**Edit:** [an example](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v048c01/v48c01.pdf).

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: @MichaelChernick   Apologies, updated with more info.

Comment: You are still using a lot of unfamiliar jargon.  First of all what are pseudoitems?

Comment: @ michaelchernick   Pseudoitems would just be a binary indicator of which response was selected.  Analogous to dummy coding.  If I have three items measured on 1-5 scale, following what I described above I would have 12 pseudoitems.  Instead of a N x 3 data matrix, I'd have a N x 12 data matrix.  Each original item would be transformed into 4 binary items (pseudoitems) indicating whether the original response was at least 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think testlet models would be *one* way to model the requested behaviour, since local dependenies among the items is explicitely modeled using independent testlet factors. However, it might be a burden (1) to have to compute all those latent testlet factors (you'll need one for each of the polytomous items that you want to decompose into pseudoitems) and (2) to have to obtain the *marginal* item discriminations and difficulties with the help of the testlet factors.

There are several different approaches to model local dependence obtained from testlet-like structures (for a great overview and comparison, see Schroeders, Robitzsch & Schipolowski, 2014). Copulas (implemented in the R package **sirt**) might be closest and most flexible to what you want to model.

However, model selection should not be guided by computational feasibility alone, but mainly by substantial theory. Note that there are several different *polytomous IRT models* that you can choose from, depending on the research question (see Penfield, 2014). Maybe the rating scale model or the nominal response model are appropriate.

Maybe the different categories of the polytomous items stem from (as you mentioned) a multidimensional cognitive/behavioral process. Then a look into Huang and Mislevy (2010) or Bechger, Maris, Verstralen, and Verhelst (2005) might help.

**References**

Bechger, T. M., Maris, G., Verstralen, H. H. F. M., & Verhelst, N. D. (2005). The Nedelsky model for multiple-choice item. In New developments in categorical data analysis for the social and behavioral sciences (pp. 187--206). Mahwah: Erlbaum.

Huang, C., & Mislevy, R. J. (2010). An application of the polytomous Rasch model to mixed strategies. In Nering, Michael L. & Ostini, Remo (Eds.), *Handbook of polytomous item response theory models* (pp. 211--228). New York: Taylor & Francis.

Penfield, R. D. (2014) An NCME Instructional Module on Polytomous Item Response
Theory Models. *Educational Measurement: Issues and Practice*, **33** (1), 36--48.

Schroeders, U., Robitzsch, A. & Schipolowski, S. (2014). A comparison of different psychometric approaches to modeling testlet structures: An example with c-tests. *Journal of Educational Measurement*, **51** (4), 400--418.